# SweetAlert-iOS in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, alerts

I'm trying to use this great library https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS

I'm managed to use it in Objective-C (it's coded in Swift) but is not working. My code is this.

```
SweetAlert* alert = [[SweetAlert alloc] init];
[alert showAlert:@"Hello"];
```

Not only the alert is not shown, but the other methods the .Swift has like "showAlert with subtitile" and many more are not exposed.

Did anyone manage yo make it work?

Comment: Does your code compile and link ?

Comment: @Starscream Yup, it compiles perfectly fine...

Comment: Apparently there's an [open issue](https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS/issues/5) about this on their github repo. Maybe this comes from their side. Try following the issue.

Comment: @Starscream Yeah i saw it, but it was posted like 15 days ago and no answer, that's why i asked here, maybe someone managed to fix ir or something. Ty anyway :)